One-to-many relationship check in Oracle
Is there a beautiful simple solution how to check if two tables have one-to-many relationship between each other using only their names as parameters? I've seen solutions with joining tables on specific fields but can I do it without knowing what foreign keys my tables have? (Or possibly get it from system tables like user_tab_columns etc.)

Do you want a NATURAL JOIN?

I would probably do want it, but afaik it takes fields with the same name. What if i have 'id' and 'worker_id' columns?

Yes, a NATURAL JOIN takes the same named columns. (20 th century construction, before each table has an id column...)

Are you looking for something like this to check two specific tables? Or a variation that shows all relations between any tables in your schema? (I'm assuming 'one-to-many relationship' just means finding a PK/UK and FK relationship, not that looking for data where there are actually multiple child rows...)

If you want to find one-to-many relationships then you are looking for the targets of a FOREIGN KEY constraint and you can find that from the data dictionary.
For example, if you have the tables:
CREATE TABLE workers (
  id        NUMBER
            CONSTRAINT workers__id__pk PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE jobs (
  id        NUMBER
            CONSTRAINT jobs__id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  worker_id CONSTRAINT jobs__worker_id__kf REFERENCES workers(id)
);

Then each job is for one worker but one worker can have many jobs.
You can find the
SELECT MAX(ucc.table_name) AS table_name,
       LISTAGG(ucc.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ucc.position) AS column_name,
       MAX(rucc.table_name) AS referenced_table_name,
       LISTAGG(rucc.column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rucc.position) AS referenced_column_name
FROM   user_constraints uc
       INNER JOIN user_cons_columns ucc
       ON (    uc.owner = ucc.owner
           AND uc.constraint_name = ucc.constraint_name)
       INNER JOIN user_cons_columns rucc
       ON (    rucc.owner = uc.r_owner
           AND rucc.constraint_name = uc.r_constraint_name
           AND rucc.position = ucc.position)
WHERE  uc.constraint_type = 'R'
AND    rucc.table_name = 'WORKERS'
GROUP BY uc.constraint_name;

Which outputs:



TABLE_NAME
COLUMN_NAME
REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME




JOBS
WORKER_ID
WORKERS
ID



Showing that the JOBS table references the WORKERS table via the WORKER_ID and ID columns, respectively.
fiddle
